# Iterando sobre dicionários aninhados (Pythônico)

Tags: python

Eu sempre fico com o pé atrás na hora de pensar em laços de repetição aninhados para iterar sobre algum contêiner (típico do C/C++), pois sei que python tem maneiras bem particulares de iterar sobre contêineres.
Para iterar sobre dicionários de dicionários só consigo pensar na solução aninhando loops como em:

```
>>> dic = {'section1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, 'section2': {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}}
>>> for x in dic:
...     print(dic[x])
... 
{'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}
{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
>>> for x in dic:
...     for y in dic[x]:
...         print(dic[x][y])
... 
value3
value4
value2
value1
```

Existe alguma forma mais "Pythônica" de fazer o mesmo? Quem sabe usando um único `for`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe sim, várias *pythonices* :P pode fazer:

#### Maneira 1

```
dic = {'section1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, 'section2': {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}}
values = [item for sublist in [dic[i].values() for i in dic] for item in sublist]
for val in values:
    print(val)
```

**Explicação**:

Para conseguirmos todos os valores de cada dicionário podemos fazer:

```
values = [dic[i].values() for i in dic] # [['value2', 'value1'], ['value3', 'value4']]
```

Para transformar esta lista de listas numa só lista, fazemos:

```
values = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist] # ['value4', 'value3', 'value2', 'value1']
```

Maneira mais simplicada:

```
dic = {'section1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, 'section2': {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}}
valuesLists = [dic[i].values() for i in dic]
values = [item for sublist in valuesLists for item in sublist] # transformar numa só lista
for val in values:
    print(val)
```

#### Maneira 2

(neste caso talvez fosse esta que eu escolheria)

```
dic = {'section1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, 'section2': {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}}
values = [dic[j][i] for j in dic for i in dic[j]]
print('\n'.join(values)) # imprimir um valor por linha, se for so para isto nao e necessario o ciclo for
```

Aqui em cima fazemos uma *[nested list compreenshion](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2009/nested-comprehensions/)*

#### Maneira 3

```
dic = {'section1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, 'section2': {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}}
values = []
valuesLists = [values.extend(dic[i].items()) for i in dic]
for k, v in values:
    print(k, v) # aqui imprime, chave valor... Se quiser que imprima só o valor retire o k do print
```

Em cima temos as chaves também, só para o valor:

```
dic = {'section1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'}, 'section2': {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}}
values = []
valuesLists = [values.extend(dic[i].values()) for i in dic]
for v in values:
    print(v)
```

**Se estiver a realizar o ciclo `for` só para fazer o print, pode atingir o mesmo resultado fazendo em vez do ciclo `for` final:**

```
print('\n'.join(values))
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra alternativa é [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

dic = {'section1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'},
       'section2': {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}
      }

valores = chain.from_iterable(map(lambda sec: sec.values(), dic.values()))

for valor in valores:
    print(valor)
    # value1
    # value2
    # value3
    # value4
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](https://repl.it/DPlo/1)</kbd>

Se preferir mostrar os valores de imediato:

```
print ( list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda sec: sec.values(), dic.values()))) )
# ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](https://repl.it/DPyJ)</kbd>

Comment: Nossa cara, dei down por engano. Tentei reverter mas está pedindo que você edite.
Faça uma pequena edição para eu poder reverter.